# What should mapping over a number or symbol produce?

Tags: core-language, map, language-design

I expected it to be an error (i.e., produce an error message), but `Map[f,num]` is `num`. Why is this the correct behavior? If it is not going to be an error, I would expect the result to be `{}`, since `Level[num,{1}]` is `{}`.

I am looking for the generalizable insight into Mma logic that implies that simply returning the value unchanged makes sense. (Better sense than an error.)

**Edit:**

My expression of perplexity seems to itself cause perplexity,
but perhaps the following observation will clarify. If I were to
try to complete the docs for `Map`, I feel I would have to add a complicated and ad hoc specification: "If no level specified in `levelspec` has parts, then return `expr`. Otherwise, apply `f` to the levels that have parts." (Set aside the special cases of `Association` and `SparseArray`.) Where else in the Mma language would such an amendment be required? Or alternatively, how can that amendment be *deduced* either from the docs or from the core behavior of the language?

Comment: There's no level to map over in an *atomic* object, so... you'll see the same behavior in `Map[f, Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}]]` or `Map[f, Image[IdentityMatrix[2]]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Associations ...

Comment: That's exactly why `SparseArray[]` and `Association[]` (just two examples off the top of my head) have special rules associated with them when interacting with list-related functions like `Part[]`.

Comment: Applying my answer in response to your edit: From the docs:  First, `Map[f, num]` = `Map[f, num, {1}]` per "Details and Options" - I assumed people knew that in my answer. Second, "`Map[f,expr,levelspec]` applies `f` to parts of `expr` specified by `levelspec`" translates to "`Map[f,num,{1}]` applies `f` to parts of `num` specified by `{1}`", which Mathematica does. There are no parts at level `{1}`, which fact you show above; so no change to the expression `num`. Third, "`Map` **always** effectively constructs a complete new expression...," but the new expression does not have to be different

Comment: I agree that an error message and failure would be better, but what can you do?

Comment: Your "apply `f` to the levels that have parts" seems pretty close the def. in the docs, just missing the role of `levelspec`. No need for the first clause about empty levels (also missing `levelspec`). If one is given instructions to do something (say `f`) to all the parts of a given thing (say `expr`) that meet a certain criterion (say `levelspec`), what does one do when there are no such parts? Give an error? Or do nothing? Seems obvious to me. If a program needs an expression of a certain `Depth[]`, then it should check that and not use some indirect way.

Comment: @JasonB. For consistency, would you say `Level[3, {1}]` and
Replace[3, 3 -> 2, {1}]` should give an error message, too? Maybe `ReplaceAll` should also give an error if there are no parts that get replaced? Somehow the logic seems clear and valid to me that "all" comprises the empty set. Somewhat like $\forall x,P(x)$ is true if the universe of discourse is empty. Perhaps such a thing needs a warning. Maybe whenever any transformation results in no change, an error message should be given? If not (I'd argue not), why just for `Map`?

Comment: This is starting to remind me of the Wason selection task somehow.

Comment: I think the edit that mentions perplexity is actually spot on--as this drags on, I am indeed getting more and more perplexed by how this behavior could cause perplexity.

Comment: Consider: `Map[f, blah[foo, bar[], fizz[buzz]], Infinity]`. The actual result is `blah[f[foo], f[bar[]], f[fizz[f[buzz]]]]`. If I'm understanding your argument, it seems like you would prefer that we actually got some sort of error. Since Infinity will always exceed the depth of the expression, we must get to a point in the computation where we are looking for elements at a level that doesn't exist, and that obligates an error. Next best would be to return `blah[{}, f[bar[]], f[fizz[{}]]]', since `{}` indicates that no application was performed. Does this accurately describe your position?

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes I do think those should error

Comment: Can someone representing the pro error camp specify what you actually mean by “error”?

Comment: @lericr To be an error is to produce an [error message](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/UnderstandErrorMessages.html). For example, how would your arguments not apply to `Part[xxx,1]` if it evaluated to `xxx`?

Comment: @lericr might have meant that an error typically results no transformation, like `Part[3, 1]` returns `Part[3, 1]` (looks like `3[[1]]`); it does not return `3`. So should `Map[f, 3]` return `Map[f, 3]` instead of `3`? Messages typically warn users that might be or are errors. Maybe ```General::noop = "`` had no effect on input ``."``` would be a welcome warning. As long as it was treated like `General::spell`, I could live with it. It still seems that you answer your own question by observing that `Level[num,{1}]` is `{}` -- i.e. there is nothing to do. *No parts, no change.*

Comment: @MichaelE2 If `Map[f,3]` evaluated unchanged and produced an error message, I would not be perplexed.

Comment: There is nothing perplexing about what happens now. I don't see how someone's perplexity about what it means to do nothing rises to the level of needing a warning.

Comment: So, for me, “error message” is completely different than “error” (or “to error” as you’ve sometimes labeled it). If the absence of a message is the only concern here, then why isn’t it sufficient to say “no error message because it conforms to the spec”? Seems like we’re done.

Comment: Your post (now) says you expect an error message. But you also ask why the behavior is correct. And you also want insight into what general principle motivates this behavior. I think part of our problem here is that you had 3 different questions, and at any moment in time we can't be sure which question you're concerned with.

Comment: A message is used to help the user correct their code. A message in this case might be helpful, but it would be very speculative and would not provide much more help than the final expression itself. That's a judgment call, but the judgment made seems very reasonable.

Comment: The behavior is correct on logical grounds. I think @MichaelE2's "No parts, no change" sums it up elegantly.

Comment: The motivating principle...well I can only speculate. It seems to me that WL tries to find the most general behavior that satisfies a function's semantics. WL is also very consistent with certain patterns, like level specs, part specs, index-ish things, and so forth. So, if those things play a role in the function's behavior, they must do so in the same way they do everywhere else. In addition, the `Map[f,num]` -> `num` behavior in this case is consistent with expression-rewriting in a way that -> `{}` would not be.

Comment: @lericr I ask again, how would your arguments not apply to `Part[xxx,1]` if it evaluated to `xxx`? Would you consider that a better behavior, more aligned with the logic of the Wolfram Language?

Comment: First, we agree that it cannot, right? That behavior would be inconsistent. However, if `Part[xxx,1]` did produce `xxx` I would expect no message. A transformation occurred. That means everything parsed and a replacement rule was found. In a re-write model of computation, that means, by definition, that no error occurred.

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted. Which question are we talking about now? Are you asking whether `Part[xxx,1]` -> `xxx` (assuming that was the actual behavior) should generate a message? (Answer = no). Are you asking why `Part[xxx,1]` does not produce `xxx`? (If that needs an answer then we've regressed). Are you asking what principle motivates `Part[xxx,1]` -> `Part[xxx,1]`? This is a fundamental aspect of how M-expressions are structured and how access to that structure is afforded. This choice is extremely elegant and allows consistency for every other structure-based function.

Comment: @lericr Neither. I want to know what part of the argument you have given for `Map` would not apply to `Part` if WL implemented it in this way. What would stop you from just giving the same set of arguments for `Part` (e.g., "no parts, no change") in this counterfactual world?

Comment: I am so confused. `Map` is one function with its own semantics. `Part` is another function with its own semantics. `Map` semantics are something along the lines of "maintain the structure but apply a function at the specified level". `Part` semantics are "return the subexpression at the specified position (and throw away everything else)". In `Map[f,expr,levelspec]`, `levelspec` is interpreted as a level-spec. In `Part[expr,position]`, `position` is a position-spec (akin to an index). This isn't inconsistency, it's different semantics.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have used "position", because `Position` gives a different representation that isn't semantically equivalent to the second argument to `Part`. I should have said `partspec` and "part-spec".

Comment: Since you brought up Haskell earlier, compare these: `map (2*) []` and `head []`. Different semantics. The first generates no error and successfully returns `[]`. The second throws an exception (and thus returns nothing--a true error). In the context of Haskell's computational model, this makes perfect sense (or at least is a reasonable choice). Would you be having the same debate on a Haskell forum?

Comment: Furthermore, why is your concern with `Map`? Shouldn't your perplexity start earlier than that? In Haskell `map f []` (assuming f is undefined) throws an exception. Why do you want (in  Mathematica) `Map[f,num]` to give you a message about elements instead of messages about `f` and `num` being undefined? Why are you comfortable with one aspect of Mathematica's philosophy that deviates from the norm but not another?

Comment: @lericr I don't think I can be any clearer than I have been about this. I chose `Part` to help you understand me, because `Map` "applies f to parts of expr specified by `levelspec`". So far, you have offered no example of aspects of your argument that could not simply be repurposed if WL had given `Part` the counterfactual behavior. (Perhaps you will, eventually.) Surely that should communicate something. Until you do that, you have not identified a motivating "philosophy" (which is precisely what I requested).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137875/discussion-between-lericr-and-alan).

Comment: The docs might be clearer written as: "`Map[f, expr]` returns  an expression identical to `expr` except that `f` has been applied to any elements at the first level."  It would then be no surprise that if `expr` has no elements at the first level, it will be returned unmodified.

Answer (score 11):

@lericr has given a nice answer, but there is another aspect of the OP's question I would emphasize. My feeling is that there is an implicit assumption in the question. The question states that a list was expected as output from an input that was not a list. `Map` does not produce lists, unless the input contains a list or the function applied produces a list. Rather, ***`Map` alters an expression by mapping a function onto some of its parts.***  I would select the second paradigm from the docs to emphasize:

> `Map[f,expr,levelspec]` applies `f` to parts of `expr` specified by `levelspec`.

"Parts" has a technical meaning in Mathematica (see `Part`). I'm sure many on the site can give a technical definition of "element on the first level" (from the first paradigm in the docs), but a good definition would use the term `Part`.  There is an exception (if thinking in terms of `Part[]` instead of `Level[]`); it is found in the "Details":

> Level `0` corresponds to the whole expression.

Alternatively, one can think of `Level[expr, levelspec]` as returning the list of parts that `Map[f, expr, levelspec` would apply `f` to. (I suppose it may be confusing that the parts are returned out of position, so `Level[]` does not completely specify what `Map` does.)

In **`Map[f, 3]`**, the expression `3` has no parts, so `f` cannot be applied to any part. The expression is returned unaltered.

If you try **`Map[f, 3, {0}]`**, you get `f[3]` per the exception quoted.

A similar thing happens with composite expressions:

```
Map[f, head[a, b], {0}]  (* f[head[a, b]] - whole expression *)
Map[f, head[a, b], {1}]  (* head[f[a], f[b]] - 2 parts @ level 1 *)
Map[f, head[a, b], {2}]  (* head[a, b] - no change  *)
```

There is no change in the last example because there are no parts at level `2`. Both `Level[3, {1}]` and `Level[head[a, b], {2}]` return `{}`, indicating that for `Map` at the same level, there are no parts to apply `f` to. *No parts, no change.*

Comment: Upvoted for the last sentence.

Comment: The question clearly states that my expected outcome from mapping over a number is an error. Short of an error, I'm not sure what to **expect** as a matter of Mma logic.  I know what the **behavior** is, but I am looking for the coherent logic behind this behavior -- the generalizable insight into Mma behavior. As a point of comparison, in Haskell it is in error. Heck, even in Python it's an error.

Comment: @Alan You're mistaken: It's not an error. The output is exactly what the documentation describes it should be, which I tried to explain: `f` is applied to every element of level `{1}` of `num`. It's a vacuously true statement, in terms of logic, since there are no elements at level `{1}`. Haskell and Python and any other language seem irrelevant, and probably they are not trying to implement `Map[f, expr, levelspec]`; more likely, they are implementing `set = Level[expr, levelspec]; Map[f, set]`, except that the user supplies the `set` directly. Their implementation doesn't alter `expr` at all

Comment: Why does your expectation of an error trump our expectation (and Mathematica's) of no error?

Comment: What if I execute this: `f[n_Integer]:=2*n;f[5.5]`? Should that return an error? I thought I explained this at nauseating length. Mathematica is inherently biased against errors, and that is a direct result of it being an expression rewriting language rather than a procedure executing language.

Comment: Python is entirely irrelevant to this discussion; it's such a completely different execution model that there is no point comparing the "error model" of Python and Mathematica. Haskell is also irrelevant, but you invoke it as an example erroneously. Haskell would impose strong, static type checks. You couldn't compile the equivalent program in Haskell, so you would get no (runtime) error. The runtime errors you could get in Haskell would fall into a completely different category of error. Is your goal here to understand Mathematica, or is your goal here to have us entertain your complaining?

Comment: Or, let's just cut to the chase. You're asking what to expect. You should expect every other possible result more than you should expect an error. And if you get what looks like an error to you, it's probably something equivalent to what would be a compile-time error in other languages. E.g. your input is malformed according to the basic syntax of the language.

Comment: Maybe a different example would help. Try executing this: `a[[`. No result is produced. That seems like the closest thing to an error to me, but it's got nothing to do with Mathematica's "philosophy of errors". You entered something that cannot even be parsed as an expression. Now execute this: `a[[1]]` (where I'm assuming there is no definition for `a`). You get a message, but the result is just `a[[1]]`. No error.

Comment: You can even continue: `a[[1]][[1]]` produces the same message, but the result is `a`. `a[[1]][[2]]` produces `1`. Everything's an expression and you can inspect and manipulate and transform expressions to your heart's content.

Comment: @lericr `a[[` produces a syntax error: Syntax::tsntxi: "a[[" is incomplete; more input is needed.

Comment: sigh. okay, I guess this is progress. Here's how I'd describe the situation with `a[[`. Evaluating `a[[` generates a message as a side effect, but it produces no result. Since there is no result, there is no error. It's closer to logging than to error-ing. If you considerf that an error, then what we have here is simply a failure to communicate.

Comment: If you think that `Map[f,num]` should generate a message as a side effect, well I guess that wouldn't be the worst thing in the world, but it would still be very much out of character for Mathematica, because the evaluation occurred exactly according to the spec with no difficulties. Nothing unexpected occurred; nothing to report. And if this is what you've been trying to say all along, it still leaves the question of what result should be produced. It should definitely not be `{}`. Have we at least convinced you of that?

Comment: I also feel like you're not really engaging with the discussion here, because I explicitly said that anything you see that looks to you like an error is probably syntax related and would be more analogous to compile time failures than runtime errors. It seems clear to me that `a[[` falls into that category.

Comment: @lericr Yes, by "be an error" I meant "produce an [error message](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/SuppressErrorMessages.html)". Like `Part[xxx,1]`. I edited for clarification.

Answer (score 10):

Be careful and rigorous here. You said your expected result is `{}`. What is that? It's an expression. It's just a display version of `List[]`. Now, what is `Map`? Per the documentation,

> Map[f, expr] applies f to each element on the first level in expr.

Okay, so `Map[f, List[1,2,3]]` gives `List[f[1], f[2], f[3]]`.

And `Map[f, List[]]` gives `List[]`.

Makes perfect sense. Interestingly, this is what you expected for `Map[f, num]`, which seems like it might cause some ambiguity. Setting that aside for the moment, consider another example:

`Map[f, List]` gives `List`.

Now, doesn't that also make sense? In these last two cases, there simply were no elements at level 1. If you want to argue that this worked incorrectly, then show me a level 1 element of the expression to which `f` was NOT applied. So, applying `f` to all of the level 1 elements is a no-op when the expression is a raw symbol. Now, what's the difference between `Map[f, List]` and `Map[f, num]`? With respect to `Map` semantics, nothing!

Run through the analogous examples `Map[f, num[1,2,3]]`, `Map[f, num[]]`, and `Map[f, num]`. It all matches up nicely. Or should I say, `Map`s up nicely!

**Edit to address the comment**

Yes, I suppose technically I begged the question. Using the implementation to describe the implementation is begging the question. But I thought an illustrative example would suffice to at least hint at the philosophy behind the implementation.

Why is it not an error? Mathematica's computational mechanism is expression evaluation/re-writing. In certain other languages, the expression (or rather statement) `num` by itself, assuming no prior definition, would be an error, because the language might require declaration. In Mathematica, expressions are just expressions and expressions are just fine. Even Lisp will require you to quote an expression if re-write rules are missing, but not Mathematica. In short, Mathematica doesn't generally try to catch mistakes and return errors. I'm not even sure what counts as a true error, maybe actual computational problems like infinite recursion (but even then you get a `Hold` as a result). And I suppose straight up syntax violations could be thought of as errors.

Why is the result not `{}`? Well, where did that expression come from? It wasn't part of the input `num`, so you're expecting it to pull something out of thin air. That's very un-Mathematica-like. Where in the documentation of `Map` do you read anything that would possibly suggest that result? `Map` keeps the head and applies the supplied function to elements at level 1. That's the spec. If you want a different spec, write your own alternate `specialMap` function.

Or, if I could speculate for a moment, are you suggesting that `{}` is informative in the way an error code or a thrown exception could be? It would be a way to tell the caller, "hey, your request didn't make sense, so here's my representation of my choice to do nothing with it". Well, again, Mathematica is based on re-writing. This isn't a procedure call. There is no return value. There are no error/status codes. Furthermore, this approach would introduce real problems. The `Map[f,num]` expression could very well be in some larger expression. If a `{}` pops up mysteriously, it completely changes the subsequent evaluation/re-writing. That would be a nightmare to debug. So, even if we wanted something like an "error" message, we'd still want to get our original expression back rather than some useless mutation of it. (Useless because we didn't get the opportunity to assign any semantics ourselves--we were left with what the Mathematica engine decided to do--and again, you could define your own function with your own semantics.)

Comment: You begged the question. Yes of course, if applying it to one symbol returns the symbol then consistency requires that apply it to another again returns the symbol. But for consistency, you could just as easily apply the specification in the docs and the way `Level` works to get a different answer.